# How to return with template literal type?

Tags: typescript

I use a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) like this:

```js
type HelloSomething = `Hello ${string}`

const string = 'World'
function sayHello(string: string): HelloSomething {
  return 'Hello ' + string
}
```

<sub>[(Playground)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhA28D2BlJBbCwAWBLAdgOZQC8UABnIklACQDeAzsAE4GEC+5AUNwMZJ8zKMzZFSUAOQB1JC3gATSdwBmAV3x9guQSICGIKsgAUo9gC4RrdgEpLR1Bix5x9blCgssalvikOpKABqKzFCbg4oIA)</sub>

However it returns this error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '`Hello ${string}`'.
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by returning a template literal instead (one that matches the template literal used in `HelloSomething`).

```
type HelloSomething = `Hello ${string}`

const str = 'World'
function sayHello(str: string): HelloSomething {
  return `Hello ${str}`; // no error
  // return `Hecko ${str}`; // error
  // return `Hello${str}`; // error
}
```

Comment: Follow up question: [How to return intrinsic string manipulation types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77798445/3416774)