# How to return intrinsic string manipulation types?

Tags: typescript

To [return with template literal type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77798239/3416774), one need to return a template literal:

```js
type HelloSomething = `Hello ${string}`

const str = 'World'
function sayHello(str: string): HelloSomething {
  return `Hello ${str}`; // no error
  // return `Hecko ${str}`; // error
  // return `Hello${str}`; // error
}
```

In a similar manner, how to return [intrinsic string manipulation types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#intrinsic-string-manipulation-types)?

```js
type Capital = Capitalize<string>
function capitalWorld(string: string): Capital { 
    return `${string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1)}` 
}
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that functions like [`toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) and [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) don't handle string literal types but instead always return an arbitrary `string`.

One possible *solution* is to make `capitalWord()` a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#generic-functions) and [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) the return value.

```
type Capital<T extends string> = Capitalize<T>;

function capitalWorld<T extends string>(str: T): Capital<T> {
    return `${str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)}` as Capital<T>;
}

const lowercase = "hello world";
const capitalized = capitalWorld(lowercase);
//    ^? const capitalized: "Hello world"
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghmAlsOAbAPAFShAHsCAOwBMBnKU4AJ0UIHMA+KAXlgWTUQC8IsGBuAFCCAZgFdCAY2CIA9oSiT2KVAHVZVVMSw58RMhWq1GACkpUAXFEwBKK-CQq+UAN6CoHqFQjAxVBQAGACQu5gB0kgAWcFQAgsAmAAw2YcCyAKpgkFTwpBAmNlAA1IZUYaSoiJL5AIw2AL4BUHDkDhwYmAKC9cKS8pRQqLIA7hBUSnksUABEkRCoQ1DDGlrTQn2EA0qOnDzEU9vt6prEJkOj4y0QNkIA9LeeUAB6APxAA)

Comment: Why use the generic function?

Comment: You need a generic to infer the literal type of the string argument.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I use `return ... as Capital` just fine?

Comment: Well, with generic the return type wil be a capitalized literal string type (e. g. `"Hello World"`) because generics allow you to infer a more specific type of the function argument than just `string`. Without generic the return is just a capitalized string (`string`). I suggest you take a look at how [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) work in TypeScript.

Comment: oh I get why you think it's better here. The `CapitalWorld()` function is just an example for the question. My actual function is more complicate than that; it doesn't simply return the capital version of the input, so I didn't see the value of generics here. Anyhow, I'll thinking about implementing generics into my case